# In What Cases Can A Dynamic Symbol Not Be Obfuscated?

Tags: actionscript-3, obfuscation

All obfuscators will say they cannot obfuscate dynamic variables, classes etc because it may result in errors. To my understanding, a dynamic symbol is one that
is programmed to have properties added or removed during run-time that may not exist at compile-time.

If I obfuscate pre-compile time, isn't that the equivelant of just naming the symbol differently in the first place, thus shouldn't cause any issues?

Comment: Yes, it's just naming the variable differently. Using an obfuscator still won't do much to it - it's not the name of a symbol that matters but its usage scenario. If the obfuscator cannot determine without doubt that a symbol is not used outside of of non-dynamic scenarios, it won't be able to obfuscate the symbol.

Comment: Note, however, that source obfuscation (I assume that's what you mean by pre-compile obfuscation) has the same problems - _you know_ when a symbol is used (and how) but the obfuscator can only guess by parsing the source. It presents the same (or more) problems as SWF obfuscation - with SWF obfuscation, at least the compiler already went through the code once and removed much of the junk.

Comment: Thanks, but basically the obfuscator has on option to include obfuscation of all variables (including dynamic). And if it does this, it may break the program. I can't wrap my head around how the code would break.

Comment: Some code can refer to variables / types by name (inside strings) - for example through reflection. The obfuscator has no idea about this - it can possibly rename a type, for example, whose name appears in a string - after obfuscation, the code will break because the string refers to a type that's been renamed. That's one way to break code through obfuscation but there are many more.

Comment: ohhh Yes! I see :] Thanks. Now if you posted that as an answer, I'd accept it! :)

Comment: I added my comment as an answer (and slightly expanded it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code can reference variables / types (symbols) using a string (e.g., strings read from resource files) - for example through reflection. The obfuscator you found is probably unable to detect when a symbol is referenced by string  - it can possibly rename a symbol, whose name appears in a string - and after obfuscation, the code will be broken because the string will reference a symbol that's been renamed.

If an obfuscator obfuscates frame labels but doesn't update strings with the new name (or resource files in the SWF), that can also lead to errors - the code may load the old name from an XML resource but the timeline doesn't have the old label anymore.

Those are simple ways to break code through obfuscation but there are many more. This is the reason most obfuscator products have 'ignore lists' - a list of symbol names (or regular expressions) to ignore during obfuscation. On large projects, maintaining the ignore list can be pretty inconvenient since one needs to remember to include all symbols that may break after obfuscation.